# Visual C++ 2010 compilers in Visual Studio 2012 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Does the Visual Studio 2012 Express (Windows Desktop SKU) bundle the Visual C++ 2010 compilers (both 32-bit and 64-bit) as part of the project round-tripping feature or does this feature only work if Visual Studio 2010 is already installed separately?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 Desktop does not support alternative platform toolsets.

if Visual Studio 2010 or Windows SDK 7.1 is already installed, you can launch the developer command prompt from those toolsets then [launch the old compiler via msbuild](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/01/11/vcbuild-vs-c-msbuild-on-the-command-line.aspx).

Comment: Not the SKU to build *Windows 8 metro apps*, I meant the SKU to build *Windows Desktop applications* (WinForms, WPF, Win32, etc)



But if your original point still stands even for this SKU, I'll accept the answer